# What is the the purpose of the inductors and diode in this schematic?

Tags: circuit-analysis

In the following schematic, 48V goes in X14 as supply then it goes to the regulator to produce the U5V.

X15 and X16 are used to supply the cooler fans.

What is the purpose of the L11, L12 and D7 in this schematic?                                                             I think that the D6 is a kind of poling protection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: what is the purpose of the L11, L12 and D7 in this schematic. I think that the D6 is a kind of poling protection.

L11 and L12, along with C42 and C43, form a low-pass filter to filter out the incoming noise. L11 (and L12, appears to be identical), on its own, may not have the enough current rating so that's probably why two of them are paralleled.

D6 is there for reverse polarity protection, to protect the circuit when the input is applied with reverse polarity (i.e. input positive connects to X14-2 and input negative connects to X14-1).

D7 (BAV99) is used as a protection diode (clamper) which basically prevents the voltage applied to X15 & X16 go below a "minus" forward drop. The other part is floating so there won't be any clamping to a positive rail (probably relies on the regulator).